# How to set max_depth and max_leaves in Python XGboost

Tags: python, constraints, xgboost, depth, leaf

I have some questions regarding the `max_depth` and `max_leaves` hyperparams in XGBoost (I'm using Python).

Let's go through some examples.

**Example 1.**
In the following case I have set:

```
max_depth = 3
max_leaves = 0
```

Note that I have also set some params for monotone_constraints.

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    objective='binary:logistic',
    base_score=0.5, 
    booster='gbtree', 
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1, 
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False, 
    gamma=2, 
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None, 
    interaction_constraints=[],
    learning_rate=0.09999999999999995, 
    max_delta_step=0,
    max_depth=3,
    max_leaves=0, #2^tree_depth 
    min_child_weight=0.9999999999999993, 
    monotone_constraints='(-1, -1, 1, 1)',
    n_estimators=12, 
    n_jobs=1, 
    nthread=1, 
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0, 
    reg_alpha=0.0009765625, 
    reg_lambda=1,
    scale_pos_weight=1, 
    silent=True, 
    subsample=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1, 
    pred_contribs=True,  
    verbosity=None)
```

The model is successfully trained and here is one of estimators (a tree):

[image]

**Example 2.**

In the following case I have set:

```
max_depth = 3
max_leaves = 0
```

Note that I have also set some params for monotone_constraints.

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    objective='binary:logistic',
    base_score=0.5, 
    booster='gbtree', 
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1, 
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False, 
    gamma=2, 
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None, 
    interaction_constraints=[],
    learning_rate=0.09999999999999995, 
    max_delta_step=0,
    max_depth=3,
    max_leaves=1, #2^tree_depth 
    min_child_weight=0.9999999999999993, 
    monotone_constraints='(-1, -1, 1, 1)',
    n_estimators=12, 
    n_jobs=1, 
    nthread=1, 
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0, 
    reg_alpha=0.0009765625, 
    reg_lambda=1,
    scale_pos_weight=1, 
    silent=True, 
    subsample=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1, 
    pred_contribs=True,  
    verbosity=None)
```

The model fails to train (the only error I get in Spyder is: Restarting Kernel ...).
**Question 1.** Why does the model not get trained? Is there an optimal parameter for `max_leaves` given a certain parameter for `max_depth`? This error occurs for `max_leaves` >= 1 and `max_leaves` <= 7. The moment I set the `max_leaves` = 8 or higher the model is successfully trained. I don't understand why.

**Example 3.**

In the following case I have set:

```
max_depth = 0
max_leaves = 0
```

Note that I have also set some params for monotone_constraints.

```
model = XGBClassifier(
    objective='binary:logistic',
    base_score=0.5, 
    booster='gbtree', 
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1, 
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False, 
    gamma=2, 
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None, 
    interaction_constraints=[],
    learning_rate=0.09999999999999995, 
    max_delta_step=0,
    max_depth=0,
    max_leaves=0, #2^tree_depth 
    min_child_weight=0.9999999999999993, 
    monotone_constraints='(-1, -1, 1, 1)',
    n_estimators=12, 
    n_jobs=1, 
    nthread=1, 
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0, 
    reg_alpha=0.0009765625, 
    reg_lambda=1,
    scale_pos_weight=1, 
    silent=True, 
    subsample=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1, 
    pred_contribs=True,  
    verbosity=None)
```

In this case I get the error:

```
XGBoostError: [20:10:14] c:\windows\temp\abs_557yfx631l\croots\recipe\xgboost-split_1659548953302\work\src\tree\param.h:232: Max leaves and max depth cannot both be unconstrained.
```

Question 2. Why is that? Why do I have to set some parameters for `max_depth` and `max_leaves`?

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: There are 2 questions in here, which makes it difficult to answer. I also suggest using proper tags for the question, as `constraints` and `leaf` are definitely not the tags that should be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaves and depth are codependent.

XGBoost needs at least 2 leaves per depth, which means that it will need at least `2**n` leaves, where `n` is depth. So for `n=3`, you would need at least `2**3=8` leaves. How can you imagine creating tree with depth 3 with just 1 leaf?

I suggest using specific package for hyperparameter optimization such as [Optuna](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Can someone leave a comment on why -1?